# Bug identification: Striped grub/worm, 5mm long, indoor highrise 9th floor, Ottawa, Canada

Tags: species-identification

I've seen two worms like the one below tonight, but none before.  A neighbour with a dog moved in next door 2 days ago, and it is close to our wall that I've seen them.  However, she hasn't seen the bug.  I saw one on the kitchen tile floor and one on the kitchen counter.  I'm in Ottawa, Canada, in a 9th floor apartment of a highrise.  I have no pets.

Not sure if it's relevant, but it also got very cold in the last 2 days (negative teens in terms of celsius) -- never seen these grubs in previous years when it got this cold.  It's mid-December.  The grub is about 5mm long.

[image]

Comment: Does this look similar? https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74209/16866

Comment: It might be, but I have a bit of doubt.  It's not as big (5mm vs.  18mm).  The answer in the page you cited hypothesize a dermestid carpet beetle, which seems [hairier and plumper](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dermestid+beetles+larvae&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjamdWUy9LtAhXoV98KHagIC1YQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Dermestid+beetles+larvae&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1AAWABg_ytoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=6wjaX5r4Beiv_QaokaywBQ&bih=607&biw=1280#imgrc=i0hhe3zhlSYC9M).

Comment: The [larvae size information is spotty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae), but sizes seem varied, so the above 5mm vs. 8mm discrepancy might not mean anything.  The stripes of a dermistid beetle seem to be due in part to its segments of its body, and my bug was too small to see this, but the stripes seemed to be due to actual colour.  But if that's what it is, I'm not liking what I find about [dealing with it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae), nor about [what it *can* eat](https://barebonesskullery.com/dermestid-beetles).

Comment: I offered the carpet beetle as an option b/c your image isn't very clear. However, after reading your description and comments with less tired eyes, I can see that even lacking a clearer image that the carpet beetle larvae is probably not the most likely candidate. Let me ask you these: did you notice any "projections" from either end of the specimen? Or does the thicker end have a broadened body segment (i.e., one that is "thicker" than the others?) Are there any type of leg-like appendages anywhere along the length? Lastly, notice any flying insects in your home lately?

Comment: Thanks for reconsidering.  I can't answer the questions beyond what I can discern from the photo because the photo is actually better than what I could see with my bare eyes (which aren't great).  So even though it may not mean much, I didn't notice any hair-like projections at the ends, and the photo shows one end thicker than the other.  I did not see any legs, and there have been no flying insects in my home.  It's beginning to look like it might not be a dermestid beetle, which I appreciate.