# Bug identification request

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone please offer a suggestion of what the insect below is?  It is about 3mm in length, and I saw it on my kitchen counter.  I live in an apartment, 9th floor of a highrise.  It is January 5 (winter), 2021, in Ottawa (-3C outside).

I suspect that is might not be relevant, but last month, I saw what might be [Dermestid lavae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/97290/bug-identification-striped-grub-worm-5mm-long-indoor-highrise-9th-floor-otta).  The beetle below, however, doesn't look like a [Dermestid beetle](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Dermestid-beetle&sclient=img&tbm=isch)

Thanks.

[image]